# What class should I invoke to post to a webform using c#?

Tags: c#, html, forms, screen-scraping, fill

I'm having a very difficult time understanding how a c# form can populate and submit a webform. i have been told to read up on httputilities and seen a few others on here but they are leaving me rather confused. If I have 3 textboxes and a submit button : username, password, email; what is the best class to envoke in order to send the form values and submit. At this point I need the program to be able to navigate to a new page within the same site.

I have viewed the source via firefox for the page in question and I have found the code where I can append it to include "value="something"" and when I load the page (saved as index.html) it will load with that text box filled, does this help me in any way at all?

Comment: You first need to understand HTTP so you know what it means to "post to a web form".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpWebRequest, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Comment: This answer was a good starting point, but unfortunately did not answer my other questions. Thank you though.